# How to call function in postgresql using casting?

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion

I try to convert **double precision** return value(31) but it does not work? Normally, select cast(31 as int); or select cast(31.0 as int);  How i can solve it?
My code below:

```
  select cast(select num_days(2019,1) as int);
```

Comment: An extra pair of parentheses would do the trick: `select cast((select num_days(2019,1)) as int);`. But the answer shows the better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the expression (the function call), not the SELECT statement:

```
select cast(num_days(2019,1) as int);
```

or simply:

```
select num_days(2019,1)::int;
```